# My Function returns a different value every time, eventhough nothing is random

Tags: java, android, corruption

I have the following code. It is used to compute texture positions for use inside OpenGL, but, that is of no concern. It works perfectly the first time, but only the first time.

```
public static float[] createTexturePositions(final int width, final int height)
{
    float[] positions = new float[width * height * 12];

    // Range: 0 - 1
    float dx = 1f / width;
    float dy = 1f / height;

    float y = 0f;

    int i = 0;

    for (int indexY = 0; indexY < height; indexY++)
    {
        float x = 0f;

        for (int indexX = 0; indexX < width; indexX++)
        {
            float top    = y;
            float left   = x;
            float right  = x + dx;
            float bottom = y + dy;

            // p1   p2
            // p3

            positions[i     ] = left;
            positions[i +  1] = top;

            positions[i +  2] = right;
            positions[i +  3] = top;

            positions[i +  4] = left;
            positions[i +  5] = bottom;

            //      p4
            // p5   p6

            positions[i +  6] = right;
            positions[i +  7] = top;

            positions[i +  8] = left;
            positions[i +  9] = bottom;

            positions[i + 10] = right;
            positions[i + 11] = bottom;

            x += dx;
            i += 12;
        }

        y += dy;
    }

    return positions;
}
```

Now, what is happening makes no sense.
- this function returns different values even when the input is exactly the same.
- Error occurs randomly
- Error doesn't occur the first time, but usually by around the 4th call, the data doesn't match the previous call.
- Values differ by a lot, here I get: 0.85714287 vs 1.1417698E35 at index i = 565. My input values are 7, 7.
- The 2nd value is the nonsensical one, in the above case (e^35). But this is the value which was just generated from scratch. I.E. there should be no way it was modified.
- I only return copies of the array's thereby ensuring that the one being tested is the one I think it is!.
- The rounding errors shouldn't matter, since they should be the same every time, and even if they are different, they should at least be similar in value.

It seems to me like a data corruption issue. Like someone or something is modifying the data on me! Is there some sort of stack heap collision issue or something weird going on here that I don't know about?

UPDATE 1:

I found that adding the following code:

```
            testValue( top    );
            testValue( left   );
            testValue( right  );
            testValue( bottom );

private static void testValue(float value)
{
    if (value < 0f || value > 1.01f)    throw new RuntimeException("Error! Value is Invalid");
}
```

prevents the problem from occurring! The testValue function is of course placed after the original function, with the calls to testValue occurring directly after the values are determined.

UPDATE 2:

I can toggle the problem on / off, just by commenting / uncommenting the testValue code. Again, it makes no sense, I think I will just leave this code in there, as it is fixing my problem for me!

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not in the function itself, but how it is used. If you want to make sure, why don't you print, for example, positions[565] from inside the function, every time. If you see it change on the 4th call, then it is the function. Otherwise look somewhere else.

Comment: I have checked it 20 times but the values are same... its  0.85714287
at 565 position. I am sure its your bug in code...

Comment: I know, it makes no sense. Please check my update. I can stop the problem by trying to debug a non-nonsensical error at it's source... Makes no sense to me.